# Having trouble with python Dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a large CSV file(28465 * 475). I need only two columns from this file, namely CBF_01 and P_NUMFLU. I'd selected these columns, but I am having problems with filtering the data from these columns. I have tried this code:

```
def average_influenza_dozes():
    fopen = pd.read_csv('NISPUF17.csv', usecols= ['CBF_01 ', 'P_NUMFLU '])     

    new_df=fopen.rename(mapper=str.strip, axis='columns')    

    var = new_df[['CBF_01','P_NUMFLU']][(new_df['CBF_01']==1) & (new_df['P_NUMFLU']!='NA')] 
    return var
```

The problem is that it returns all the values from the column P_NUMFLU for which CBF_01==1. What I mean is, it's not filtering the second column.

Please give some suggestions.

Comment: Change "&" operator to "|"

Comment: Changing "&" to "|" would return me all of the 28465 rows. then how could i filter out the rows?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is working well. I think the mistake is how you are understanding logical operators

Here you're telling python: bring columns that `d2['CBF_01']==1` AND `d2['P_NUMFLU']!='NA'`

```
var = d2[(d2['CBF_01']==1) & (d2['P_NUMFLU']!='NA')][['CBF_01','P_NUMFLU']]
```

If you need either `d2['CBF_01']==1` OR `d2['P_NUMFLU']!='NA'` you should change `&` and use `|` instead:

```
var = d2[(d2['CBF_01']==1) | (d2['P_NUMFLU']!='NA')][['CBF_01','P_NUMFLU']]
```

How logical operators work:
[image]

Comment: I guess you didn't get my Question. If I use OR operator instead of AND, it won't filter out the rows (and return me all 28465 rows). But, I want to filter the rows as well. I want that it should return me only those rows for which 'CBF_01==1' AND 'P_NUMFLU != 'NA'. I hope that i made myself clear.

Comment: If you can share a sample of your .csv I can improve my code. Thank you!